# IC with configurable output : high-side, low-side, push-pull

Tags: push-pull, high-side, low-side

As the title mentions, I need to implement a design that would require an IC that can be driven in high-side, low-side, or push-pull configuration. The main purpose for this is that I need to drive some I/O with current sensing depending on the configuration. The voltage on those specific I/O goes from 4.5 to 36V. I've done some research and didn't find anything relevant, is there any IC that can accomplish this?

Comment: When you say high-side and low-side, do you mean pull ups? Why don't you include what load you are driving. Current sensing is achieved with amplifiers and ADC's , it's also not clear in the question if you need a range from 4.5 to 36V or if it's a digital High Low scheme

Comment: What are you trying to achive? What do you mean by low side and high side? You talk about push-pull, but that's a signalling method when high/low side are ways to define location. If you mean pull up/down or open-drain/open-source, you can't mix them with push-pull signalling because they do different things, and behave in different ways. What are you trying to achieve, why do you think you need this particular IC?